# How to get current monitor scale

Tags: c++, windows, screen-resolution

I have tested my program on laptop, with standard ressolution, with view scale 125%.
[image: Windows setting]

I have following code to get this scale factor:

```
HWND activeWindow = ::GetActiveWindow();
HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(activeWindow, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
HMONITOR monitor1 = MonitorFromWindow(activeWindow, NULL);
DEVICE_SCALE_FACTOR scDev = GetScaleFactorForDevice(DEVICE_PRIMARY);
DEVICE_SCALE_FACTOR scMon, scMon1;
GetScaleFactorForMonitor(monitor, &scMon);
GetScaleFactorForMonitor(monitor1, &scMon1);
```

But all results is `"SCALE_100_PERCENT (100)".` I expected `125`.
What do I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It is quite magical.

```
double scMon = 1.0;
HWND activeWindow = ::GetActiveWindow();
HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(activeWindow, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
UINT x, y;
if (SUCCEEDED(GetDpiForMonitor(monitor, MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI, &x, &y)) && (x > 0) && (y > 0))
  scMon = 1.0 * x / USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;           // 1.25
  // scMon = MulDiv(100, x, USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI);  // 125
```